# Cant figure out how to bind a jQuery event

Tags: jquery

So I have a page here: http://8wayrun.tv/

Its has a JS file here:

```
/** @param {jQuery} $ jQuery Object */
!function($, window, document, _undefined)
{
    $('#headbar').load( function($form)
    {
        $( this ).addClass( "test" );
    });
}
(jQuery, this, document);
```

Its a relatively simple JS file; all its doing is binding to the element `#headbar` and adding the class `test`. However, for some reason, its not adding the class to the `#headbar`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element doesn't yet exist when your JavaScript runs. You need to put your DOM-manipulating code in a [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) callback.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  /** @param {jQuery} $ jQuery Object */
  !function($, window, document, _undefined)
  {
    $('#headbar').load( function($form)
    {
        $( this ).addClass( "test" );
    });
  }
  (jQuery, this, document);

});
```

Comment: Though the no-conflict style anonymous function would make more sense outside the `$(document).ready(function () {`.

Comment: okay... I made those changes to my JS file, and its still not working.

Comment: Then crack open your developer tools and start doing some debugging. Start with a `debugger` statement and make sure your `$('#header')` is selecting an element.

Comment: No time like the present to learn. We can't do it for you. If you have any intention of doing software development on the web, it's going to be your most-used tool.

Comment: The problem is you can't just say "use photoshop" for someone who asks  how to draw an image. Thats not helpfull.

Comment: Actually, I would do exactly that. I'm certainly not going to draw it for them. If you're writing code, you should be comfortable debugging that code. Again: No time like the present to learn. You can't come running to Stack Overflow every time you encounter a problem with code you've written.